# Relationships one to many Between table in .NET core 3.1 API return null list object

Tags: c#, .net, api

I making Dotnet API.
I have class Topic and class Tag.
1 Topic will have many Tags, and 1 Tag only have 1 Topic.
When I run with postman: http://localhost:5000/api/topics , for getAllTopic it's return null list of Tag, and
when run  : http://localhost:5000/api/tags , for getAllTag didn't return null object of Topic.

Here is my code

class: Tag

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace NewAndNotificationAPI.Models{
    public class Tag{


        [Key]
        public int tagId { get;  set; }
        [Required]    
        public string name { get;  set; }
        [Required]
        public string status { get;  set; }
        [Required]
        public string description { get;  set; }

        [Required]
        public int topicId { get;  set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual Topic topic {get;set;}
    }
}
```

class: Topic

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace NewAndNotificationAPI.Models{
    public class Topic{

        [Key]
        public int topicId { get;  set; }
        [Required]
        public string name { get;  set; }
        [Required]
        public string status { get;  set; }
        [Required]
        public string description { get;  set; }

        public virtual List<Tag> tags{get;set;} =new List<Tag>();

    }
}
```

class: DatabaseContext:

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using NewAndNotificationAPI.Models;

namespace NewAndNotificationAPI.Data{
    public class NewAndNotificationContext:DbContext{
        public NewAndNotificationContext(DbContextOptions<NewAndNotificationContext> opt):base(opt){

        }
        public DbSet<Topic> Topics{get;set;}
         public DbSet<Tag> Tags{get;set;}

         protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder){
             base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
             modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
             .HasOne<Topic>(tg => tg.topic)
             .WithMany(t => t.tags )
             .HasForeignKey(tg => tg.topicId);

         }

    }
}
```

Please help me.